cmake chicken and egg problem - run process before or as part of the cmake configure step
Much like this: Build a program at CMake configure time
In my case, I need to run a PYTHON script that generates a number of C functions, and that python script generates a CMAKE file that should be used as part of the configuration process.
-- Background
My source code is orginized into a a series of subdirectories, each area of interest often has a UNIT_TEST_somename() function that is the unit test for that area or subject.
I have a python script that searches all of the source code and finds the UNIT_TEST_somename() functions and creates little "main.c" files/applications, one for each UNIT_TEST it finds. This python script will also generate a CMAKE file for these application.
This is a chicken and egg problem.  (A) I need CMAKE to run a command to generate both C and CMakeLists.txt files as part of the CMAKE Configure time so that (B) Later, at "Makefile" time - when Make (or Visual Studio...) is executed all of the unit test executables are created as part of the build process.
In effect, if I have 20 UNIT_TEST_functions() scattered about in my source code, then the script will create 20 sub directories - one for each UNIT_TEST and put the application main.c and corresponding CMakeList.txts file in their directories.
The Upper Level CMAKE file just includes all subdirectory CMAKE files
The question is: I do not want to run the python script THEN when complete, run CMAKE, I want CMAKE to run the Python script - first, then process the Subdirectories.
This is not unlike requiring to run a SCRIPT of some sort to create a "version.c/h" file that will be used by all of the other parts of the Build process.

Just execute the script via execute_process and then descend into directory created by it via add_subdirectory.
